# How to pass JSON input for Map<Person, Person> type to a PUT JAX-RS API?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS REST endpoint of PUT type and I am supposed to pass a Map to this API.

```
@PUT
@Path("/some/path")
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
        MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response updatePerson(HashMap<Person, Person> map) {

//some code here
}
```

I generated JSON for Person class but I am not able to pass it as a JSON input to this API. I am using Postman client and it says Syntax error while I try to pass the JSON input as key value pair. JSON generated for Person looks something like below

```
  {"name":"abc","weight":100.0,"id":"123"}
```

I need to pass this as key value pair as a map. Something like

```
 {
   {"name":"abc","weight":100.0,"id":"123"} : 
   {"name":"def","weight":200.0,"id":"123"}
 }
```

Any pointers how do I do this?

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't have objects as keys, they need to be strings. Can you work your way around that by using a serialised person as the key? Or restructure the data?

Comment: Use a unique attribute of Person as key instead? Like `id` unless that is not unique like in your example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change that. Is there a way to pass JSON input to this map?

Comment: I didn't look to carefully at the annotations earlier but for @Consumes you have PLAIN_TEXT in the list.

Comment: @raghav `{
   {"name":"abc","weight":100.0,"id":"123"} : 
   {"name":"def","weight":200.0,"id":"123"}
 }` this is invalid `JSON` payload. Check with [online validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). You need to parse it manually. In controller change `Map` to `String` and deserialise it manually by defining some kind of custome deserialiser.

Comment: @MichałZiober Hi Michel. Thanks for reply. Yes I know thats an invalid payload as Postman itself is giving syntax errors. I was just trying to give an idea of what I was expecting. May be I have no other option than to send it as String and deserialize back there.

Comment: @raghav, can you change controller implementation? Can you change `Map` for something else?

Comment: @MichałZiober I don't recall much about this scenario now but your comments certainly helped me back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it looks like a bad idea to create `Map` like this. `JSON Object` can be converted to `Java` `Map` where `key` is `String` and `value` is any `Object`: can be another `Map`, `array`, `POJO` or simple types. So, generally your `JSON` should look like:

```
{
    "key" : { .. complex nested object .. }
}
```

Theres is no other option. If you want to have in `Java` mapping `POJO` -> `POJO` you need to instruct deserialiser how to convert `JSON`-`String`-`key` to an object. There is no other option. I will try to explain this process using [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library because it is most used in `RESTful Web Services`. Let's define `Person` class which fits to your `JSON` payload.

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private double weight;
    private int id;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String value) {
        String[] values = value.split(",");
        name = values[0];
        weight = Double.valueOf(values[1]);
        id = Integer.valueOf(values[2]);
    }

    public Person(String name, double weight, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return id == person.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "," + weight + "," + id;
    }
}
```

Because it is used in `Map` as key we need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Except `public Person(String value)` constructor and `toString` method everything else looks pretty normal. Now, let's take a look on this constructor and `toString` method. They are in correlation: `toString` builds `String` from the `Person` instance and constructor builds `Person` from `String`. We can call first transformation as *serialisation* and second as *deserialisation* of our key in `Map` serialisation and deserialisation. *(Whether these two are well implemented this is another story. I just want to show an idea behind it. Before using on production should be improved)*

Let's use this knowledge and `Jackson` features to serialise and deserialise `Map<Person, Person>`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // register deserializer for Person as keys.
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addKeyDeserializer(Person.class, new PersonKeyDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        // Create example Map
        Person key = new Person("Rick", 80.5, 1);
        Person value = new Person("Morty", 40.1, 2);
        Map<Person, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();
        personMap.put(key, value);

        // Serialise Map to JSON
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(personMap);
        System.out.println(json);

        // Deserialise it back to `Object`
        MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(HashMap.class, Person.class, Person.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, mapType).toString());
    }
}

class PersonKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return new Person(key);
    }
}
```

Above code prints as first `JSON`:

```
{
  "Rick,80.5,1" : {
    "name" : "Morty",
    "weight" : 40.1,
    "id" : 2
  }
}
```

As you can see, `Person`'s `toString` method was used to generate `JSON` `key`. Normal serialisation proces serialised `Person` to `JSON` object. As second below text is printed:

```
{Rick,80.5,1=Morty,40.1,2}
```

This is a default representation of `Map` and it's keys and values. Because both are `Person` object it's `toString` method is invoked.

As you can see there is an option to send `JSON` as `Map<Person, Person>` but key should be somehow represented. You need to take a look on `Person` class implementation. Maybe you will find some similarities to my example. If no, maybe it was configured somehow. First of all try to send in `PostMan`:

```
{
   "123" : {"name":"def","weight":200.0,"id":"123"}
}
```

Or:

```
{
   "{\"name\":\"abc\",\"weight\":100.0,\"id\":\"123\"}":{
      "name":"def",
      "weight":200.0,
      "id":"123"
   }
}
```

Maybe it will work.

See also:

- [Map Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map)
- [Custom ObjectMapper with Jersey 2.2 and Jackson 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872931/custom-objectmapper-with-jersey-2-2-and-jackson-2-1)
- [JBoss resteasy - Custom Jackson provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838240/jboss-resteasy-custom-jackson-provider)